# Keep Chrome Extension Even When Loading

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I built a Chrome Extension that places a div element on the screen. When I reload the page the div element momentarily goes away because the DOM of the page is loading. Is it possible to keep the div element on the screen even when the page is loading?

Comment: No, it's not possible in the strict sense, but you can come close by running your content script at `document_start` and waiting for document.body in MutationObserver, then add the element.